# Find and Upserts on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb document with schema as below

```
{
    "userid":"abc123",
    "applications": [
        {
            "app_id":"12345",
            "name":"application_1",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "settingid":"1",
                    "settingkey":"refreshTime",
                    "settingValue":"20mins",
                    "isActive":"yes",
                    "updatedOn":"2017-06-22"
                },
                {
                    "settingid":"2",
                    "settingkey":"refreshTime",
                    "settingValue":"10mins",
                    "isActive":"no",
                    "updatedOn":"2017-06-22"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "app_id":"8999",
            "name":"application_12",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "settingid":"1",
                    "settingkey":"refreshTime",
                    "settingValue":"20mins",
                    "isActive":"yes",
                    "updatedOn":"2017-06-22"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "userid":"abc",
    "applications": [
        {
            "app_id":"12345",
            "name":"application_1",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "settingid":"1",
                    "settingkey":"refreshTime",
                    "settingValue":"20mins",
                    "isActive":"yes",
                    "updatedOn":"2017-06-22"
                },
                {
                    "settingid":"2",
                    "settingkey":"refreshTime",
                    "settingValue":"10mins",
                    "isActive":"no",
                    "updatedOn":"2017-06-22"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "app_id":"8999",
            "name":"application_12",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "settingid":"1",
                    "settingkey":"refreshTime",
                    "settingValue":"20mins",
                    "isActive":"yes",
                    "updatedOn":"2017-06-22"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

find if a user exists.
If user exists find if an application exists.
If application exists find the setting. 
If setting exists update setting or insert the new setting.

```
db.usersettings.find({"userid":"abc123"})

db.usersettings.find({applications.name:"appname"})

db.usersettings.find({applications.settings.settingKey:"settingkeyname"})
```

How to perform all these queries in a single query by checking the existence and doing an insert and upsert on the db.

Comment: The third and most deep request here is not possible, without knowing the exact array position at which to update. The problem as is documented with the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) ( which facilitates the second request ) is that the returned matching  index is only ever that of the "outer" array here and cannot determine position within an "inner" array. So this is the big flaw with your structure. You need to "flatten" the data to be contained within one array at most. Or move to separate collections, as is appropriate.\

Comment: In short, you really need to basically "denormalize" this so that the only array entries are essentially the `"settings"`. Of course, then the `"app_id"` and `"name"` become additional properties on those items instead of *'items nested within the application"*. This is how MongoDB works. You simply cannot "nest" indefinitely and expect to work with this in an efficient manner.

Comment: @NeilLunn so the document structure should be simple to query?

Comment: What *"I just described ?"* Then yes. What you have here, is not workable. Bottom line is https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831 . Not the number on the ticket. Issues have nearly hit 30,000 so I do not see this one resolving differently any time soon.